Generate a product ID from text values in Google Sheet
I have a list of products in a Sheet, each product has several values that determine the final name.
For exemple :

Product : familly, product type, resort
SubProduct : familly, product type, resort and customer cateegory

I would like to use that list to import it in another system. For this i would like to create an unique ID for each product and subproduct using a number for exemple. If a product has the same setting (the ID should be the same) to be able to store them as subproduct from the product.
I hope i was clear in my problem.
Exemple of data:

I searched on google, but i think i have a lack of vocabulary in english to find exactly what i am looking for. I tried some formulas that i found but not working. Maybe you can help me in searching better or help me in proposing a formula ?
Thank you

I added an image with Data from my sheet. To create the ID i was thinking to add number code for Univers, Famille and T. Produit then use a concatanation + vlookup to have an id, i also need to take into consideration the "Produit" name creating unique value for each item. If i have twice the same name in "Produit", the value should be the same. Output would be then xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx for "univers value"-"famille value"-"t. produit value"-"produit value"
